# Node js API with HTTPS not working when hosting on IIS Server

Tags: node.js, https, iis-8

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('newapi:server');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
    
var https_options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./cert/Cellde.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/Cellde.pem')
};


var server = https.createServer(https_options, app, function (req, res) {
    res.render('./index', { title: 'Express' });
 });

server.listen(port);
```

**When deploy on IIS Server gives below error**

**Read/Write Permission are there for all folder but still getting the error**

iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x6d
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1013
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

The node.exe process has not written any information to stderr or iisnode was unable to capture this information. Frequent reason is that the iisnode module is unable to create a log file to capture stdout and stderr output from node.exe. Please check that the identity of the IIS application pool running the node.js application has read and write access permissions to the directory on the server where the node.js application is located. Alternatively you can disable logging by setting system.webServer/iisnode/@loggingEnabled element of web.config to 'false'.

Comment: You can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184878/how-to-host-node-js-app-on-iis-10-with-windows-server-2019

Comment: thanks ! I have the same code, its working  on  localhost perfectly but when I deploy  my  code to live server its not working

Comment: I find a question with the same error, you can try the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028537/iisnode-encountered-an-error-when-processing-the-request